# Moving items between folders in a SharePoint 2010 list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-foundation

Is there a way to move items or folders around in a SharePoint 2010 list? It has to be in SharePoint List, I have a single list, with multiple folders and items within those folders. Can I move an item to a different folder within that list without being required to delete the items and/or folder and manually recreate the item/folder in the new desired location? 
My Requirement is to move a new item to a folder automatically on save if it is not created in the folder specified.

Comment: Did you try Open with explorer option? You can move docs and folders with that option

Comment: What i want is to do it as and when document is saved. I do not want to transfer it manually myself
Like say there is a folder named 2016 in the list Client. So someone clicking directly on "Add new Item" will get the form to fill details and document be saved. I want to do is on save check if the document is being saved inside folder or not, if not run a script or so and send it to folder, if yes then let it get saved in respective folder.
Please note the folders are named based on years, so i have 2016,2015, so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Site Content and Structure Manager in SharePoint to move items between the lists. See [How to Use the Site Content and Structure Manager in SharePoint 2013](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/07/29/how-to-use-the-site-content-and-structure-manager-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx) for more information

**Update**

The update is based on the comment. If you want to automatically move the items, then you can either write an event handler (itemadded) or you may use workflows.

Comment: What i want is to do it as and when document is saved. I do not want to transfer it manually myself
Like say there is a folder named 2016 in the list Client. So someone clicking directly on "Add new Item" will get the form to fill details and document be saved. I want to do is on save check if the document is being saved inside folder or not, if not run a script or so and send it to folder, if yes then let it get saved in respective folder.
Please note the folders are named based on years, so i have 2016,2015, so on.

Comment: @ShashankVerma, see my updated answer. The functionality you are looking for is not available out of the box. you need to do coding for this.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Nadeem, what i was able to get from little googling any workflow will create the document, then update in the folder and delete the previous created record.
I use Nintex for workflow, if possible  please help if this is the only solution or can we do something else using workflows.